# How to create new assoc array using two other assoc arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two associative arrays:

```
$array1=[key1=>$value1,key2=>$value2,key3=>$value3];
```

`$array2=[key1=>$value1,key2=>$value2,key4=>$value4];`

How to create the following array:

```
 $arraytotal=[key1=>$value1,key2=>$value2,key3=>$value3,key1=>$value1,key2=>$value2,key4=>$value4];
```

array_merge is not an option because i have to keep the same values in the final array.
Tnx.

Comment: It's not possible. When you add an index that already exists, it will replace the old one. There can not be two `key1`, for example.

Comment: You can't get it exactly as you type here since two keys can't have the same name. But you can get a multidimensional array with similar result.

Comment: This is the best you can get. https://3v4l.org/dQiPW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have multiple keys set to the same value (you have key1 in each array), and as you've seen, the second key1 will override the first when you use array_merge.

Your options depend on if each original array functions as a separate group of key/value pairs, or if you want similar key/value pairs grouped together.

So, the first one is easy:

```
$array1=[key1=>$value1,key2=>$value2,key3=>$value3];
$array2=[key1=>$value1,key2=>$value2,key4=>$value4];

$super = [$array1, $array2];
```

The second needs a bit more looping:

```
$array1=[key1=>$value1,key2=>$value2,key3=>$value3];
$array2=[key1=>$value1,key2=>$value2,key4=>$value4];

$super = [];

foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $super[$key] = [$value];
}

foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
    if (!isset($super[$key])) {
        $super[$key] = [];
    }

    $super[$key][] = $value;
}
```

If you know that you'll always have the same keys in each array, then you can skip the `isset`